# Django rest update (and partial_update) after retrieve action

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, restframeworkmongoengine

I don't understand one thing into DRF(or DRFMongoengine).

```
class SomeViewSet(MongoModelViewSet):

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        print "ACTION:", self.action
        return SomeSerializer
```

After calling url for this viewset from cURL(or with get-parameters format=json), I observe:

```
ACTION: retrieve
[09/Jan/2017 17:19:08] "GET /api/some/?format=json HTTP/1.1" 200
```

After calling with format=api (eg from browser), I observe:

```
ACTION: retrieve
ACTION: update
ACTION: partial_update
ACTION: update
[09/Jan/2017 17:21:50] "GET /api/some/?format=api HTTP/1.1" 200 73173
```

Why is that happening? Will be very thankful for any help.

Comment: What happens if you call with format=api from curl? Same behavior?

Comment: Yes, same behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the browsable API needs to get the serializers to display the update forms plus some permissions.
As one may define different serializers based on the action, the API has to query each of them.